# Is there a way to detour a c++ constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, detours

Funny thing is, I answered a question not too long ago about getting the address of a C++ constructor saying that it can't be done so use perfect forwarding instead.  However, in terms of detouring using Microsoft's Detour library, this isn't an option.  The address *is* required in order to detour any call. So now I have to ask the question, if there is no address of a constructor, is it even possible to detour one?  And if so, how?

Comment: A constructor has a memory address (it is executable code afterall, so it has to reside *somewhere* in memory). You just cannot use the `&` operator to obtain that address (the language standard forbids it). But, if you know how your compiler lays out the structure of the class in memory, you can probably get the constructor's address through "creative" means. But I would not advise it.

Comment: Well, @RemyLebeau, seems that *creative* would have to be the way to go.  I know that this is ***definitely*** not going to be portable, and I'm not looking for it  to be.  So long as it works under a MS C++ compiler, I'd be happy.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about MS Detour, but I usually hooking detour manually with inline assembly in C++. If the code (constructor instance) is mapped in memory, and you can write to that memory region, then detouring ***is possible***.

- The basic mechanism of hooking detour is find the place to replace the original opcode by a JUMP to your code cave. If the JUMP code doesn't match the size of the original opcode, fill it with NOPs.
- Execute the original opcode in your code cave
- PUSHAD & PUSHFD
- Doing anything you want using global variables (recommended)
- Call any custom function without params
- POPFD & POPAD
- Jump back to the patched opcode (skill some bytes of NOPS)

For the first step, to obtain the address of the constructor instance, you need to search for its dynamic address either by ReadProcessMemory or any method. I did detour a function from a DLL that load dynamically. To obtain the function, I use `HANDLE tempHandle = GetModuleHandle((LPCWSTR)"DLLFileName.dll");` and go by the offset of the DLL handle.